# Can I run two for loops in one statement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can I run two for loops in one statement in javascript? Would I do it like this?

```
for(initialize1,initialize2; condition1,condition2; incrementation1,incrementation2)
```

Comment: Try it `for(var i = 0, j = 0; i <= 10 && j <= 10; i++, j++){ console.log(i + j) }`

Comment: **TL;DR:** Yes, in the initializer and loop (not the condition) sections, with commas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can do a for loop like that, but you have one and just one condition for check. If you can make it check just a one condition for all of your variables for example an And (&&) conditional expression this will work fine, or if you just use the other variables for do something else it will work fine too.

Try it:

```
for(var i=j=k=0; j<9 && k<12;i++, j++, k++){
    console.log(i,j,k);      
    i = 12;
}
```

@samdonly1

Always you will have just one evaluation, but you can do something like this:

```
function evalFor(i, j, k){
   if (k == 9) return false;
   else if (j == 7) return false;
   else if (i == 12 && j == 6) return false;
   else return true;
}
for(var i=j=k=0; evalFor(i, j, k);i++, j++, k++){
    console.log(i,j,k);     
    i = 11;
}
```

In this case you can check your variables i, j, k in other function and decide if the loop stops or goes on.

Comment: thanks, is there a possibility that i could use different condition for different variables

Comment: @samdonly1 yes, i edited the original answer added a new example.

Answer (score 4):

Which one of these do you mean? This will execute one loop and wait for either condition1 or condition2 to fail:

```
for (initialize1, initialize2; condition1 && condition2; incrementation1, incrementation2)
```

This will execute one loop nested inside the other:

```
for (initialize1; condition1; incrementation1)
    for (initialize2; condition2; incrementation2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I mean, the way I did something like this was basically trying to access a nested array in position [0,2],[1,1],[2,0]
My solution was simple.
ran a counter every time it looped

```js
let matrix = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
]
let leftDiag = []
let rightDiag = []
let counterJ =matrix.length-1
for(let i =0;i<matrix.length; i++){
  leftDiag.push(matrix[i][i])
  rightDiag.push(matrix[i][counterJ])
  console.log(i, counterJ)
  counterJ-=1
}
console.log(leftDiag)
console.log(rightDiag)
```